# Why am I rendering HTML code?

Tags: php, rendering

I am currently doing a small project in PHP using Notepad++, I am using Xampp and everything was rendering fine until I did an php include above the  tag. Before it was rendering like so [Before Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moaqQ.png) and now it is just showing up entirely with HTML code [After Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOupQ.png).

Here is my code -

```
    <?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Shout It !</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>SHOUT IT! Shoutbox</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="shouts">
                <ul>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                    <li class="shout"><span>10:15PM - </span>Brad : Hey What Are you guys up to.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="input">
                <form method="post" action="process.php">
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
                    <br/>
                    <input class="shout-btn" type="submit" name="submit"value="Shout It Out !" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this as I have never come across this before and have been sat trying solutions for the last few hours ?

Comment: You get the contents because you're opening the file over the filesystem (notice the `file:///`). You need to open the website over the web (e.g. access the website with `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`).

Comment: One thing to note is that the code you have posted here and the "after render" image do not match. In your image you are missing a semi-colon in this code `<?php include 'database.php'; ?>`. Check the code on your server and make sure you have that semi-colon.

Comment: I will check the localhost now thanks

Comment: Just addition for @CharlotteDunois comment above, you cant just right click *.php file to 'open in chrome/firefox/ie' etc. You need to run it via server process either local or online.

Comment: For some reason when I am trying to use Localhost it says the file can't be found when I am looking directly at it in the folder ?

Comment: Go to [`http://localhost/Shoutitnew/index.php`](http://localhost/Shoutitnew/index.php).

Comment: Ah I have found it thank you for your help